# how to install java into azure docker environment?

Tags: java, azure, docker

my boss gave me a docker environment on azure.
i need to use java but my azure environment does not have it.
so i requested my boss to change the azure environemnt to another one which is available for java.
but my boss said that its impossible. so that i need to install java to the current environment.

i tried to install java by adding the following statement to my docker file.

```
RUN apt-get update  -y \
  && apt-get install -y default-jdk
```

but the following errors have been shown.

```
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update  -y   && apt-get install -y default-jdk' returned a non-zero code: 100
##[error]The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update  -y   && apt-get install -y default-jdk' returned a non-zero code: 100
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 100 Finishing: Build and push an image to container registry
```

my source.list is the following:

> deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
>
> deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
>
> deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main

how can i resolve the problem?

---

oh no, i fixed it myselef by adding the following scripts to my docker file.

```
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install apt-utils
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install openjdk-11-jdk-headless
```

Comment: There's no such thing as a "docker environment on azure" or "azure environment". Do you mean "virtual machine"?

Comment: hi i fixed it myself by adding the following scripts to my docker file:RUN 
apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install apt-utils
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install openjdk-11-jdk-headless